# How to highlight the searched text in textbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using JavaScript in my application. I want to highlight the search element as well as keep the cursor at the position of search item in textbox. How can I highlight the element using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://webcloud.se/log/Selecting-text-with-JavaScript/